# Getting Data From Scanned Answer Sheets

Tags: c#, image-processing

How to view the data that is being called by the scanned answer sheet? The scanned answer sheet contains the ID number and that ID number corresponds to a certain data of a person.
The ID number is identified by shading.

Thank you for your kind response.

Comment: Are you in the same class as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352527/checking-scanned-test-paper-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? What errors/problems do you face? Do you may have codesnippets that show what you tried so far? How do your sheets look like?